# Como crear un archivo Bacpac para poder ser restaurado en Azure usando SQL 2008 y SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, azure

He tratado de buscar y no encuentro nada que me indique como hacerlo. Tengo bases de datos en SQL 2008 y SQL 2012. Necesito generar archivos Bacpac para que puedan ser importados y restaurados en Azure.

Cuando trato de hacerlo con SQL Manager me da el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna forma de hacerlo con SQL Manager o Visual Studio?

Gracias de ante mano

Answer (score 0):

Si bien lo puedes hacer directamente en el SQL Management Studio, Yo lo utilizo dentro de un proyecto de base de datos en Visual Studio 2015 
Debes instalarte la ultima versión de

- [SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx)

(o puedes buscar la version para VS que tienes)
Alli vas a poder crear uno de cero, o importar una DB existente. Luego podras publicar la DB y generar el archivo .bacpac, incluso puedes publicar directamente en Azure ;)

Puedes tener mas informacion

- [Cómo: Crear un nuevo proyecto de base de datos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh272677.aspx)

Lo bueno... que puedes gestionar los cambios, comparar la DB para subir solamente los cambios que tieenes, poder importar o exportar estos cambios (traer cambios que esta en el server), incluso comparar no solo el esquema de artefactos (tablas, procedimientos, funciones, etc) sino tambien comparación de datos.

PD: Dale una mirada si puedes a VS2017 tiene una nueva forma de gestionar proyectos de Base de datos, con herramientas de RedGate

Answer (score 0):

Cada versión de SQL Server tiene diferentes característica. SQL Server en Azure tiene unas cuantas incompatibilidades. Microsoft tiene [una herramienta](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595) que permite analizar cada base de datos y mostrar si es o no compatible y en caso que no lo sea, ver cual es el problema para intentar solucionarlo.
También tiene [un servicio](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/dms/dms-overview) para poder hacerlo.